# Converting swing application to web application

Tags: java, swing, web-applications

I have implemented a Swing application. I need to this application to web application for better look and feel.

The *[WebCream](http://www.creamtec.com/webcream/)* software is one of software to convert Swing to web applications. I'm getting trouble how to convert using this software.

Please let me know any suggestion to make conversion. I need information to make this conversion using any software.

Comment: We have no idea what trouble you are having so we cant give you any suggestions.

Comment: @Shoban im not finding information regarding for how to convert   swing to ajax.I mean have u any ideas on that?

Comment: Impossible. While the Swing widgets may be emulated by Ajax (IIRC it has been done) the whole application logic does work different (client/server). You have to rewrite a lot of the application. GWT would make it a little easier in this case, it has similar paradigms. If it is only about looking good - it is possible to build nice looking Swing applications.

Comment: Looks like their website has some demos etc - Did you not find that useful ? But I warn you. Do not do this, you will end up with code you can not manage - Unless the tool company supports you a 100%. We had a nightmare of an application which was converted from MS access to swing.

Answer (score 5):

For a Swing developer Vaadin's API is a very low step to take. The API is analog and the programming model as well. And the applications written in both frameworks are mostly business applications.

And it's open-source and free, and we've been working on it since 2001. For more check out: https://vaadin.com/swing

Comment: Should add to that with Vaadin the UI code is executed in JVM like in Swing app, so you can keep using the same libraries, "advanced" JVM features like reflection, Java 8 and alternative JVM languages. Thanks to "thinclient" built with GWT, the end users still need no JVM installed on their application (nor other browser plugins).

Answer (score 0):

Consider [GWT](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/). If you have a good MVC code, then most of your code will be reused.

Even if this is not the case, then you will keep writing your application in java with similar design patterns (in many cases).

Answer (score 0):

There is open source project [webswing.org](https://webswing.org) running under AGPL. It is a web server where you deploy your swing application. The application is rendered to html canvas through websockets, so you get the exact same look and feel like on desktop.